# Android two layers overlapping scroll layout like Airbnb room detail layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to have a two layers overlapping scroll layout like Airbnb room detail layout

**Airbnb-like overlapping scrolling:**
[image]

But **my XML layout file** outputs the following result:

[image]

**Here is my layout code:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backdrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/height_360_2" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="always">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:contentPadding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:text="@string/person_intro" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: These two seem quite similar to me. Difference that I see is that yours goes all the way to the top, ey? Try adding `marginTop="50dp"`  and seeing if it changes anything.

Comment: @Vucko thank you.
nice, it works now with adding marginTop in Cardview 
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:contentPadding="16dp">

Comment: Cool, then I'll move my comment to the answer so you can award me by accepting. No problem :)

Comment: thanks for reminding hint, I did add marginTop, but in 
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="always">,  scrolling would not over the marginTop area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment helped solve:

> These two seem quite similar to me. Difference that I see is that yours goes all the way to the top, ey? Try adding marginTop="50dp" and seeing if it changes anything.

Adding a correct `marginTop` fixed it:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
app:cardElevation="8dp"
app:contentPadding="16dp">
```

Comment: If there is a Toolbar and image ViewPager behind the top scrolling cardview, it seems that the touch event would not pass to the toolbar and viewpaer. Any ways to solve the issue?

Comment: Hm, I'm not really sure... You can try searching online for something like "passing the onTouch event to the parent" or something similar.